# `ulimit` a shell, not a user

Tags: ulimit

We're multiple user to work on a same account

I want to limit my activities to not hang the computer, to not bother the other users. I want to limit my resources' usage to not use it all (because if a process can, it uses it all)

There are 2 approaches, the priority one and strict limit one. Problem is, Linux don't manage very well priorities, meaning you'll slow down other activities even with the worse priority. So it let the strict limit

But I want to limit only my shell, not the account that many person uses

Do you have suggestions regarding priorities or strict limit?

Comment: `ulimit` will set the resource limits of the current shell process. Is this not what you want?

Comment: From what I read, it set it for users, and you have to restart the shell, who miss the whole point

Comment: It is usually considered bad practice for multiple users to use one account.  Is there any way that you can create an account for each user?You may need to consider group accesses and/or ACLs, but you'll have a much more robust system and one that can easily have limits applied.

Comment: Then you will have to refer to that text in your question because that's not what it does. It sets the resource limits for the current process, i.e. the current shell. You don't have to restart the shell after giving the `ulimit` command in a shell session. Also, why are you working on the same account? Using the same machine is fine, but I see no reason to share accounts for any sort of work.

Comment: I have no such control of the politic of the system. I can't create a user or parameter, a whole ACL/Group access system. I only have to run my tasks without bothering the others

Comment: Um, if you're sharing one account, there are no "other users".

Comment: Other persons**

Answer (score 3):

`ulimit` *can* be used for this: it sets the limits for the current shell, not for the user globally or for future shells; and these limits are inherited by processes started in that shell.

To convince yourself of that, open two shells with the same user on the same system; examine the limits (`ulimit -a`) in both, then in one of them, set limits using `ulimit`, and then run `ulimit -a` again in the other shell — the limits applied in the first shell won’t affect the second shell.

The limits set by `ulimit`, on Linux, are described in detail in [the `setrlimit` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html). They aren’t really useful if you want to “play nice” with other users’ workloads on a shared system; they prevent runaway processes from contributing to resource exhaustion (*e.g.* one can prevent processes from creating huge files).

You might want to look into [cgroups](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html) if they are available on your system, and accessible to you as a regular user. These give more control over memory, CPU and I/O usage, which is what typically creates problems on multi-user systems.

Comment: What cgroups can give me more ? Where can I learn extensively how to use each options of `ulimit`? The `man` doesn't explain the set limits, only the command refuses to operate if i'm out of bounds. What are the minimal parameters for each flags? (not to use as is but to know the bounds)

Comment: How to modify scheduling priority, pipe size, real-time priority ? It doesn't seem to work. Does cgroups permit modification on a shell only and on real time without reloading anything?

Comment: `ulimit` sets limits; it doesn’t change priorities. As indicated in the documentation, you can’t change the pipe size, you can only view it. cgroups sets limits on process trees, without reloading anything (you can create a cgroup and move processes into it).

Comment: So I can only view scheduling priority and real-time priority?

Comment: You can *set the limits* on priorities. You need other tools to set priorities (`nice`, `chrt`).

Comment: It doesn't seem to let me *set the limits*. `$ ulimit -S -e 1 -r 1 -P 1 -T 1` `bash: ulimit: -P: invalid option` `bash: ulimit: -T: invalid option` `bash: ulimit: scheduling priority: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument` `bash: ulimit: real-time priority: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument`